# Rough estimation/calculation of the efficiency of a fusion reactor

Tags: fusion, efficient-energy-use

Where are the losses during the reaction. In the creating of the electromagnetic field? The heat released by the fast moving neutron? or something else?

Comment: You want to read this article, it covers most of these issues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_energy_gain_factor

Comment: This does not seem at all like a homework question, the OP appears to want to understand where the energy goes. I'd like to post a detailed answer.